# Failed to load module Razorpay

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, razorpay

The following images are part of my app. I am using swift 5.0 which I have already given in image. I have installed pod from https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/ios-integration/standard/.   website. In that razorpay for swift 5.0 is given. I followed the same steps. In my podfile , I have written also version,but still the updated pod has been installed. So I have many issues which I have put in following images. I have no solutions. I also downloaded razorpay SDK for swift 5.0, but same issue with SDK. I tried both methods:

- Using SDK
- Using pod
  But always it gives same error. I have no solution. Please anybody who has used it, plz give solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vd1Q.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukMkr.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpc3D.png `enter code here`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxfKd.png

Comment: Did you add Razorpay in 'Link library with libraries' ?

Comment: No. Right now I am using pod. I am using swift 5. So I gave specific version 1.1.1  in podfile which I found from razorpay docs. But it automatically install 1.1.7.

Comment: Please add your Framework and Clean build.

Comment: plz share photo where to add?? I added as per video uploaded by razorpay. So I don't know where it should be added?

Comment: @GrishmaSagar did you get any solution. I'm also stuck here. Please help if you've found any solution,

Answer (score 1):

Please Update your pod.

```
pod 'razorpay-pod', '~> 1.1.5'
```

After that please declare your variable like this.

```
import Razorpay

var razorpay: RazorpayCheckout!

razorpay = RazorpayCheckout.initWithKey(RAZ_API_KEY_TEST, andDelegate: self) //Change your key based on test or live
```

Comment: By default it is updated as 1.1.5. This is not supported by swift 5.0. It is only supported by  swift 5.0+ versions. That is my actual problem. I am mentioning version in podfile still it is automatically installed as 1.1.5. That's why errors are generated which I have put in images

Comment: Still I followed whatever you suggested. But I am getting same erros

Answer (score 0):

Make xcode install specific version of pod using:

```
pod 'razorpay-pod', '1.1.5'
```

This solved same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your Framework & Library inside `Link Binary With Libraries` and clean and build your project.

[image]

Comment: Module compiled with Swift 5.0 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.3 compiler. This error I am getting after I followed your answer

Comment: Better we can connect through remote so I can check the issue. I recently used RazorPay and working fine.

Comment: Fine, Which remote desktop you are using? And how you will solve it??

Comment: Anydesk? if possible

Comment: ok. Which xcode and swift versions are you currently using?